# Unable to deploy my rails application to fly.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application called `gratify_me` that is running on rails version `6.1.4.1` & ruby version: `2.7.2`.

I want to deploy my application to [fly.io](https://fly.io/) and the first command I ran was `fly launch` and it was successfully able to create the PostgreSQL database.

Now when I run `fly deploy` it shows me this error:

```
...
...
=> ERROR [stage-4 8/8] RUN bin/rails fly:build                                                                                                                         3.5s 
------
 > [stage-4 8/8] RUN bin/rails fly:build:
#25 3.411 Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /app/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
------
Error failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -c ${BUILD_COMMAND}]: exit code: 1
```

From the error, it looks like it is looking for the master key but it's unable to find it from the specified path even though I do have the `master.key` file in the mentioned path.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `master.key` in `/config/master.key`.

So, in order to create one you have to run: `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`, which will run the editor, `vim` in this case.

I hit `q!` right after it was opened, and the key was generated.
This will generate also `credentials.yml.enc` in the same path as `master.key`.

With this you can deploy to fly.io.

Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/db0sch/19c321cbc727917bc0e12849a7565af9) from which I picked up this solution.
Hope it helps.

Make sure you exclude master key file from git, in `.gitignore`:

```
# Ignore master key for decrypting credentials and more.
/config/master.key
```